# How to Convert CMSampleBuffer/UIImage into ffmpeg's AVPicture?

Tags: iphone, ios4, avfoundation, video-encoding, libav

I'm trying to encode iPhone's camera frames into a H.264 video using ffmpeg's libav* libraries. I found in this
[Apple's article](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1702.html) how to convert CMSampleBuffer to UIImage, but how can I convert it to ffmpeg's AVPicture?

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Answering my own question:

```
CVImageBufferRef pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);

// access the data
int width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer);
int height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer);
unsigned char *rawPixelBase = (unsigned char *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer);

// Do something with the raw pixels here
// ...

// Fill in the AVFrame
CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);

AVFrame *pFrame;
pFrame = avcodec_alloc_frame();

avpicture_fill((AVPicture*)pFrame, rawPixelBase, PIX_FMT_RGB32, width, height);
```

Now `pFrame` is filled in with the content of sample buffer, which is using the pixel format `kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA`.

This solved my issue. Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't the call to avpicture_fill() occur before the call to CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(), since the former accesses raw pixel data in the CVImageBufferRef?