# How to effectively transfer real time video between two iOS device (Like facetime, skype, fring, tango)

Tags: iphone, video-streaming, real-time

I know how to get frame from iOS sdk. 
[How to capture video frames from the camera as images using AV Foundation(http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1702/_index.html)]
It's pixel, and i can transfer it to JPEG.

What the way I want to transfer the video is like this:

One iOS device A:

1. Get the pixel or JPEG from call function

`-(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection`

2. Using existed technology encoding to h.264 - ffmpeg
3. encapsulate video with TS stream
4. Run http server, and wait for request

The other iOS device B:

1. http request to A(using http simply instead of rtp/rtsp)

So my question is, do I need to use ffmpeg to get h.264 stream or i can get from iOS API?
If I use ffmpeg to encode to h.264(libx264), how to do that, is there any sample code or guideline?

I've read the post  [What's the best way of live streaming iphone camera to a media server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474871/whats-the-best-way-of-live-streaming-iphone-camera-to-a-media-server/5293729#5293729)
It's a pretty good discussion, but i want to know the detail.

Answer (score 0):

The license for ffmpeg is incompatible with iOS applications distributed through the App Store.

If you want to transfer realtime video and have any kind of a usable frame rate, you won't want to use http nor TCP.

Answer (score 0):

Although this doesn't directly answer your question about which video format to use, I would suggest looking into some 3rd party frameworks like [ToxBox](http://www.tokbox.com) or [QuickBlox](http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-videochat-ios). There is a fantastic tutorial using Parse and OpenTok here:

http://www.iphonegamezone.net/ios-tutorial-create-iphone-video-chat-app-using-parse-and-opentok-tokbox/