# Ios rotate, filter video stream in ios

Tags: ios, video-streaming, avfoundation, gpuimage, red5pro

Hello There I am rotating and applying image filters by GPUImage on vide live stream
The task is consuming more time than expected resulting over-heating of iPhone
Can anybody help me out in optimising my code
Following is my used code:

```
- (void)willOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer{
    //return if invalid sample buffer
    if (!CMSampleBufferIsValid(sampleBuffer)) {
        return;
    }

    //Get CG Image from sample buffer
    CGImageRef cgImageFromBuffer = [self cgImageFromSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
    if(!cgImageFromBuffer || (cgImageFromBuffer == NULL)){
        return;
    }

    //We need rotation to perform
    UIImage *rotatedPlainImage = [UIUtils rotateImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImageFromBuffer] byDegree:90];
    if (rotatedPlainImage == nil) {
        CFRelease(cgImageFromBuffer);
        return;
    }

    //Apply image filter using GPU Image on CGImage
    CGImageRef filteredCGImage = [self.selectedPublishFilter newCGImageByFilteringCGImage:rotatedPlainImage.CGImage];

    //Convert back in CMSamplbuffer
    CMSampleBufferRef outputBufffer = [self getSampleBufferUsingCIByCGInput:filteredCGImage andProvidedSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];

    //Pass to custom encode of Red5Pro to server for live stream
    [self.encoder encodeFrame:outputBufffer ofType:r5_media_type_video_custom];

    //Release data if needed
    CFRelease(outputBufffer);
    CFRelease(filteredCGImage);
    CFRelease(cgImageFromBuffer);
}


- (CGImageRef)cgImageFromSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef) sampleBuffer // Create a CGImageRef from sample buffer data
{
    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);        // Lock the image buffer

    uint8_t *baseAddress = (uint8_t *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0);   // Get information of the image
    size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer);
    size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
    size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    CGContextRef newContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, 8, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
    CGImageRef newImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(newContext);
    CGContextRelease(newContext);

    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);
    /* CVBufferRelease(imageBuffer); */  // do not call this!

    return newImage;
}

- (CMSampleBufferRef)getSampleBufferUsingCIByCGInput:(CGImageRef)imageRef andProvidedSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer{
    CIImage *nm = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer;
    CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorSystemDefault, (size_t)nm.extent.size.width, (size_t)nm.extent.size.height, kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA, NULL, &pixelBuffer);
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress( pixelBuffer, 0 );
    CIContext *ciContext = [CIContext contextWithOptions: nil];
    [ciContext render:nm toCVPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer];
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress( pixelBuffer, 0 );
    CMSampleTimingInfo sampleTime = {
        .duration = CMSampleBufferGetDuration(sampleBuffer),
        .presentationTimeStamp = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer),
        .decodeTimeStamp = CMSampleBufferGetDecodeTimeStamp(sampleBuffer)
    };
    CMVideoFormatDescriptionRef videoInfo = NULL;
    CMVideoFormatDescriptionCreateForImageBuffer(kCFAllocatorDefault, pixelBuffer, &videoInfo);
    CMSampleBufferRef oBuf;
    CMSampleBufferCreateForImageBuffer(kCFAllocatorDefault, pixelBuffer, true, NULL, NULL, videoInfo, &sampleTime, &oBuf);
    CVPixelBufferRelease(pixelBuffer);
    CFRelease(videoInfo);
    return oBuf;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used OpenGL 2.0 and Accelerate Framework

Accelerate framework to rotate CMSampleBuffer

Now without filter the time is 3 - 8 milliseconds

With Filters its 7-21 milliseconds

OpenGL to make CI Image render fast on CVPixelBuffer

```
@implementation ColorsVideoSource{
    CIContext *coreImageContext;
}

- (instancetype)init{
    if((self = [super init]) != nil){

        EAGLContext *glContext = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];
        GLKView *glView = [[GLKView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 360.0, 480.0) context:glContext];
        coreImageContext = [CIContext contextWithEAGLContext:glView.context];

    }

    return self;
}

- (void)willOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer{
    if (!CMSampleBufferIsValid(sampleBuffer)) {
        return;
    }
    CVPixelBufferRef rotateBuffer = [self correctBufferOrientation:sampleBuffer];
    CGImageRef cgImageFromBuffer = [self cgImageFromImageBuffer:rotateBuffer];
    if(!cgImageFromBuffer || (cgImageFromBuffer == NULL)){
        return;
    }

    UIImage *rotatedPlainImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImageFromBuffer];

    if (rotatedPlainImage == nil) {
        CFRelease(rotateBuffer);
        CFRelease(cgImageFromBuffer);
        return;
    }

    if (_currentFilterType == SWPublisherFilterNone) {
        if (_needPreviewImage) {
            _previewImage = rotatedPlainImage;
        }
        CMSampleTimingInfo sampleTime = {
            .duration = CMSampleBufferGetDuration(sampleBuffer),
            .presentationTimeStamp = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer),
            .decodeTimeStamp = CMSampleBufferGetDecodeTimeStamp(sampleBuffer)
        };
        CMVideoFormatDescriptionRef videoInfo = NULL;
        CMVideoFormatDescriptionCreateForImageBuffer(kCFAllocatorDefault, rotateBuffer, &videoInfo);
        CMSampleBufferRef oBuf;
        CMSampleBufferCreateForImageBuffer(kCFAllocatorDefault, rotateBuffer, true, NULL, NULL, videoInfo, &sampleTime, &oBuf);
        CFRelease(videoInfo);

        if(!self.pauseEncoding){
            @try {
                [self.encoder encodeFrame:oBuf ofType:r5_media_type_video_custom];
            } @catch (NSException *exception) {
                NSLog(@"Encoder error: %@", exception);
            }
        }
        CFRelease(oBuf);

    }
    else {

        CGImageRef filteredCGImage = [self.selectedPublishFilter newCGImageByFilteringCGImage:rotatedPlainImage.CGImage];
        if (_needPreviewImage) {
            _previewImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:filteredCGImage];
        }
        CMSampleBufferRef outputBuffer = [self getSampleBufferUsingCIByCGInput:filteredCGImage andProvidedSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
        if(!self.pauseEncoding){
            @try {
                [self.encoder encodeFrame:outputBuffer ofType:r5_media_type_video_custom];
            } @catch (NSException *exception) {
                NSLog(@"Encoder error: %@", exception);
            }
        }
        CFRelease(outputBuffer);
        CFRelease(filteredCGImage);

    }
    CFRelease(rotateBuffer);
    CFRelease(cgImageFromBuffer);
}

#pragma mark - Methods Refactored GPUImage - Devanshu

- (CVPixelBufferRef)correctBufferOrientation:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
{
    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer        = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);

    size_t bytesPerRow                  = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer);
    size_t width                        = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
    size_t height                       = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);
    size_t currSize                     = bytesPerRow * height * sizeof(unsigned char);
    size_t bytesPerRowOut               = 4 * height * sizeof(unsigned char);

    void *srcBuff                       = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);

    /* rotationConstant:
     *  0 -- rotate 0 degrees (simply copy the data from src to dest)
     *  1 -- rotate 90 degrees counterclockwise
     *  2 -- rotate 180 degress
     *  3 -- rotate 270 degrees counterclockwise
     */
    uint8_t rotationConstant            = 3;

    unsigned char *dstBuff              = (unsigned char *)malloc(currSize);

    vImage_Buffer inbuff                = {srcBuff, height, width, bytesPerRow};
    vImage_Buffer outbuff               = {dstBuff, width, height, bytesPerRowOut};

    uint8_t bgColor[4]                  = {0, 0, 0, 0};

    vImage_Error err                    = vImageRotate90_ARGB8888(&inbuff, &outbuff, rotationConstant, bgColor, 0);
    if (err != kvImageNoError) NSLog(@"%ld", err);

    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);

    CVPixelBufferRef rotatedBuffer      = NULL;
    CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes(NULL,
                                 height,
                                 width,
                                 kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA,
                                 outbuff.data,
                                 bytesPerRowOut,
                                 freePixelBufferDataAfterRelease,
                                 NULL,
                                 NULL,
                                 &rotatedBuffer);

    return rotatedBuffer;
}

void freePixelBufferDataAfterRelease(void *releaseRefCon, const void *baseAddress)
{
    // Free the memory we malloced for the vImage rotation
    free((void *)baseAddress);
}


- (CGImageRef)cgImageFromSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef) sampleBuffer // Create a CGImageRef from sample buffer data
{
    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
    return [self cgImageFromImageBuffer:imageBuffer];
}

- (CGImageRef)cgImageFromImageBuffer:(CVImageBufferRef) imageBuffer // Create a CGImageRef from sample buffer data
{
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);        // Lock the image buffer

    uint8_t *baseAddress = (uint8_t *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0);   // Get information of the image
    size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer);
    size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
    size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    CGContextRef newContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, 8, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
    CGImageRef newImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(newContext);
    CGContextRelease(newContext);

    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);

    return newImage;
}

- (CMSampleBufferRef)getSampleBufferUsingCIByCGInput:(CGImageRef)imageRef andProvidedSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer{
    CIImage *theCoreImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

    CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer;
    CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorSystemDefault, (size_t)theCoreImage.extent.size.width, (size_t)theCoreImage.extent.size.height, kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA, NULL, &pixelBuffer);
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress( pixelBuffer, 0 );

    [coreImageContext render:theCoreImage toCVPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer];

    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress( pixelBuffer, 0 );
    CMSampleTimingInfo sampleTime = {
        .duration = CMSampleBufferGetDuration(sampleBuffer),
        .presentationTimeStamp = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer),
        .decodeTimeStamp = CMSampleBufferGetDecodeTimeStamp(sampleBuffer)
    };
    CMVideoFormatDescriptionRef videoInfo = NULL;
    CMVideoFormatDescriptionCreateForImageBuffer(kCFAllocatorDefault, pixelBuffer, &videoInfo);
    CMSampleBufferRef oBuf;
    CMSampleBufferCreateForImageBuffer(kCFAllocatorDefault, pixelBuffer, true, NULL, NULL, videoInfo, &sampleTime, &oBuf);
    CVPixelBufferRelease(pixelBuffer);
    CFRelease(videoInfo);
    return oBuf;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this create memory issue when you use this while video recording ?

Comment: No, didn't made any, you can try just release any object that is not wanted dear.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSLog(@"start rotate");
CFAbsoluteTime t0 = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
CIImage *ciimage = [CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer];
CFAbsoluteTime t1 = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
NSLog(@"dur to ciimage: %@", @(t1-t0));

CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);
CIImage *newImage = [ciimage imageByApplyingCGOrientation:kCGImagePropertyOrientationRight];
CFAbsoluteTime t2 = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
NSLog(@"dur rotate ciimage: %@", @(t2-t1));

CVPixelBufferRef newPixcelBuffer = nil;
size_t width                        = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer);
size_t height                       = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer);

CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, height, width, kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA, nil, &newPixcelBuffer);
CFAbsoluteTime t3 = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
NSLog(@"dur alloc pixel: %@", @(t3-t2));
[_ciContext render:newImage toCVPixelBuffer:newPixcelBuffer];
CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);
CFAbsoluteTime t4 = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
NSLog(@"dur render pixel: %@", @(t4-t3));

//
CMSampleTimingInfo sampleTimingInfo = {
    .duration = CMSampleBufferGetDuration(sampleBuffer),
    .presentationTimeStamp = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer),
    .decodeTimeStamp = CMSampleBufferGetDecodeTimeStamp(sampleBuffer)
};

//
CMVideoFormatDescriptionRef videoInfo = nil;
CMVideoFormatDescriptionCreateForImageBuffer(kCFAllocatorDefault, newPixcelBuffer, &videoInfo);

CMSampleBufferRef newSampleBuffer = nil;
CMSampleBufferCreateForImageBuffer(kCFAllocatorMalloc, newPixcelBuffer, true, nil, nil, videoInfo, &sampleTimingInfo, &newSampleBuffer);

CFAbsoluteTime t5 = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
NSLog(@"dur create CMSample: %@", @(t5-t4));
// release
CVPixelBufferRelease(newPixcelBuffer);
CFAbsoluteTime t6 = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
NSLog(@"dur end rotate: %@", @(t6-t0));
return newSampleBuffer;
```

Comment: Please explain your lines of code so other users can understand its functionality. Thanks!